# TypeError: on_delete must be callable

Tags: python, django-models

```
File "C:\Users\sungk\Git\django_website\blog\models.py", line 5, in <module>     class Post(models.Model):
File "C:\Users\sungk\Git\django_website\blog\models.py", line 10, in Post     author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=True)   File "C:\Users\sungk\Git\django_website\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 813, in __init__     raise TypeError('on_delete must be callable.') TypeError: on_delete must be callable.
```

Comment: Share your `Post` model.

Answer (score 2):

The [**`on_delete=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete) can *not* be `True`. It should be a callable, a function. Usually it is one of the builtins as [described in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete). This can be [**`CASCADE`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.CASCADE), [**`PROTECT`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.PROTECT), [**`RESTRICT`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.RESTRICT), [**`SET_NULL`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.SET_NULL), [**`SET_DEFAULT`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.SET_DEFAULT), [**`SET(…)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.SET), or  [**`DO_NOTHING`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DO_NOTHING).

Strictly speaking you can also make your own callable, but that is only applicable if you want to do something more sophisticated than the ones listed above.

The `on_delete=…` specifies what to do with the *related* `Post`s in case the `User` object that is the author is removed. By using `CASDCADE`, the related `Post` objects will be removed:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.FOreignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I got understood. btw what if I stick to: from django.contrib.auth.models import User... then do I need to change on_delete=models.Cascade, sth like this??

Comment: @PeterKam: yes, you can still use the `User` model (although the documentation explicitly says that this is a bad idea), but you need to specify *what* to do in case the `User` is removed to the related posts (the `Post`s for which that user is an `author`), since you can not keep referring to a non-existing user.

Comment: @WilliemVanOnsem: Okay I see... Thank you! got so impressed your prompt reply and deep knowlege :). I fixed my problem. it works now

Comment: @PeterKam: it is `__str__`, not `__dir__`.

Comment: stupid... I noticed that now. fixed it :)

Comment: Thank you so much. I am in Sydney now. it's 12:37am. I put `__dir__` instead of `__str__ ` I do so many mistakes... anyway you are so kind! appreciate that.